# Operating a 60 hz Induction motor at 50 hz

Tags: math, induction-motor, vfd

If i had an Induction motor that runs on 460 volts ,35 amps , develops a power of 35 hp at a speed of ~1800 RPM ( data acquired from a nameplate )

How is it possible to calculate the same parameters if i wanted to run this motor at 50 hz instead ? what equations should i use ? , all i know is that power would decrease as well as RPM (obviously).

Comment: lower f means higher current and less margin to flux saturation on core resulting excess heat..

Comment: You can do it in most cases, but the power output will drop to about 0.75-0.85 of the plate rating at 60 Hz. This might help you: http://www.usmotors.com/TechDocs/ProFacts/50Hz-Operation-60Hz.aspx

Comment: For sure you can run it at 50 Hz at reduced voltage. You would use 460V * 50 Hz / 60 Hz = 383 V. Power and RPM's would be similarly reduced. Of course you might not have that Voltage handy unless you are using some kind of VFD. I have seen some motors rated for both 60 Hz and 50 Hz. Are you sure the nameplate makes no mention of 50 Hz ratings? Is it a totally enclosed, fan cooled (TEFC) motor?

Comment: @mkeith: Actual maximum voltage for that motor is more likely to be 480 Vac.  That also implies that it is a 3-phase motor.  Applying the correction factor of 50/60 leads to an input voltage of 400 Vac.  This is mighty close to the 415 Vac available from many European countries.

Comment: @DwayneReid very good point.  It's a happy accident; we have a heritage of 240 doubled to 480 delta/wye for industrial, while their residential mains power is aimed at 230/leg which works out to 400 wye.  Sounds like the reverse would work too; a Euro 400V-50 motor would run ok at 480-60, albeit at higher speed.

Comment: @DwayneReid, I was just going by the reported name plate data. What you say makes sense and all. Would be nice to confirm with data from the manufacturer or additional name-plate data. I know I have seen a lot of motors rated for both 208 and 240 (in the US) at the same power right on the name plate. It would be nice if manufacturers would put 50 Hz data on the name plate as well, so no guessing is required.

Answer (score 1):

Motor torque is a direct function of the design ratio of voltage and frequency, or the V/Hz ratio. Anything within +-10% of the design V/Hz ratio will allow the motor to develop design torque without significant added heating.

480V is the DISTRIBUTION voltage in North America, the ***actual*** NEMA motor DESIGN voltage is 460V to allow for voltage drop. A motor labeled as 460V 60Hz is designed for a V/Hz ratio of 7.67:1 (460/60) and if you multiply that back into 50Hz, that's where you get the 383V. So giving it anywhere between 345 and 420V at 50Hz should be absolutely fine for that motor. It will develop full torque, but because of the frequency being 5/6ths, will run 17% slower. because the mechanical power (HP or kW) is a function of speed and torque and your torque remains the same, the power will also drop by 17%, so if it was rated for 35HP, that will be roughly 30HP or 22kW.

Given that 35HP was never a "standard" NEMA HP rating for an AC induction motor (standards are 30HP and 40HP), my guess is that your motor STARTED OUT life as a 22kW 380V 50Hz motor (which IS a standard size) and was re-rated for use in North America as "35HP" at 460V 60Hz. So if you want to go back to running it on a 380-415V 50Hz system again as a 22kW motor, have at it.